# Laravel: Undefined offset in view index.blade.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my routes I have this route defined as:

```
// app/routes.php
Route::resource('CharacterController');
```

The corresponding method in the controller is:

```
// app/controllers/CharacterController.php
public function index(){
    $characters = Character::all();
    $houses = House::all();

    return View::make('characters.index')->with(array('characters'=>$characters, 'houses' => $houses));
}
```

Finally, in the view:

```
// app/views/characters/index.blade.php
#this fires an error:
{{ $houses[$characters->house_id]->name }}

# at the same time this gives correct result: 
{{ $houses[1]->name }}

# and this IS equal to 1:
{{ $characters->house_id }}
```

Comment: Is this because $characters->house_id is a string? Try an     intval() on it and see what happens.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, tried it already, but unfortunately gives the same Undefined Offset error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `id` as index of the array to access the object with given id.

Since you have an Eloquent Collection you can use its various functions. One of them being `find()` for retrieving one item by `id`

```
{{ $houses->find($characters->house_id)->name }}
```

Comment: Works, thanks :) 
But if I call `find()` in the view what's the point of getting `all()` houses in the controller? I mean I could just do `{{ House::find($character->house_id)->name }}` and since this is in a `foreach()` cycle does it mean it will make N database calls to the house table? I'm confused

Comment: Not exactly. `House::find()` runs on the DB `$houses->find()` on the collection of houses you already fetched. So it just performs the search in memory without querying the database again.